# How to convert already created appointment to a Edit mode by using outlook add-in/office js

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

I created outlook appointment and need shift edit mode  programmatically using outlook add-in when stay in the read mode .
is there office js function available to move read mode to edit mode ?

i am looking function like this

```
Office.context.mailbox.displayAppointmentEditForm(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the feature you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on `user-voice` are considered when we go through our planning process.